# Математические функции в цикле SCSS

Tags: css, sass, scss

Всем привет.

Подскажите, как сделать цикл такого плана с помощью SASS:

```
@for $lvl from 1 through 7 {
  .ul-lvl_#{$lvl}
  {
    width: (5% * #{$lvl});
  }
}
```

Нужно, чтобы

- Длина первого элемента равнялась 5%
- Второго - 10%
- Третьего - 15%
- И так далее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так:

```
@for $lvl from 1 through 7 {
    .ul-lvl_#{$lvl} {
        width: #{$lvl*5+'%'}
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все сработало.